# uploading files from python to GCS

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I'm able to list the buckets of GCS from Python boto.
Able to copy files to GCS using gsutil command.
Able to download files from GCS to compute instance using python API.
I have followed steps from below document.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/gspythonlibrary

Getting below error in uploading files from instance to GCS.

GSResponseError: 403 Forbidden
`AccessDenied`Access denied.Provided scope(s) are not authorized

Answer (score 1):

That generally happens when you did not include the storage scopes in the access scopes when you set up the vm.  Unfortunately you cannot change them after you start the vm, you will need to recreate it.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#accesscopesiam

Answer (score 0):

It could also happen if you did not set environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, which should be your service account key.